# Issue while fetching Google+ Circle information using Google+ Domain API

Tags: api, google-plus

I am developing a small web application wherein I am integrating with Google+ Domain API's.
I am using OAuth2 authentication.I have generated client_id and client_secret for my web application 
from Google API console.
Using Google+ Domain API's, I am able to generate the access token.

1. Generating authorization URL

   ```
   List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList(
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write");

   //Sets up Authorization COde flow
   GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
       new JacksonFactory(),
       "xxx","yyy",SCOPE).setApprovalPrompt("force").setAccessType("offline").build();

   //Builds the uthorization URL
   String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(<REDIRECT_URI>).build();
   out.println("<div id='googleplus'></div><a href='"+url+"' rel='external' ><img src='googleplus.jpg'></a> <b>Configure</b></div>");
   session.setAttribute("CodeFlow", flow);
   ```
2. After authorization

   ```
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow=(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow)session.  getAttribute("CodeFlow");

   //After authorization,fetches the value of code parameter
   String authorizationCode=request.getParameter("code");

   //Exchanges the authorization code to get the access token
   GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse=flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode).
       setRedirectUri(<REDIRECT_URI>).execute();

   GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(new  NetHttpTransport()).setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
   .setClientSecrets("xxx", "yyy")
   .addRefreshListener(new CredentialRefreshListener(){

       public void onTokenErrorResponse(Credential credential, TokenErrorResponse errorResponse) throws java.io.IOException{
           System.out.println("Credential was not refreshed successfully. "
                   + "Redirect to error page or login screen.");

       }


       @Override
       public void onTokenResponse(Credential credential, TokenResponse tokenResponse)
               throws IOException {
           System.out.println("Credential was refreshed successfully.");
            System.out.println("Refresh Token :"+tokenResponse.getRefreshToken());

       }
   }).build();

   //Set authorized credentials.
   credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
   credential.refreshToken();
   ```
3. Fetching circle information:

   ```
   PlusDomains plusDomains = new PlusDomains.Builder(
           new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
           .setApplicationName("DomainWebApp")
           .setRootUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/")
           .build();
   PlusDomains.Circles.List listCircles=plusDomains.circles().list("me");
   listCircles.setMaxResults(5L);
   System.out.println("Circle URL:"+listCircles.buildHttpRequestUrl());
   CircleFeed circleFeed=listCircles.execute();
   System.out.println("Circle feed:"+circleFeed);
   List<Circle> circles =circleFeed.getItems();

   while (circles != null) {
         for (Circle circle : circles) {
             out.println("Circle name : "+circle.getDisplayName()+" Circle id : "+circle.getId());
         }

         // When the next page token is null, there are no additional pages of
         // results. If this is the case, break.
         if (circleFeed.getNextPageToken() != null) {
           // Prepare the next page of results
           listCircles.setPageToken(circleFeed.getNextPageToken());

           // Execute and process the next page request
           circleFeed = listCircles.execute();
           circles = circleFeed.getItems();
         } else {
           circles = null;
         }
       }
   ```

I get the below error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
```

Note: I have also enabled Google+ Domain API in my Google API Console.
  `REDIRECT_URI ="http://localhost:8080/DomainWebApp/oauth2callback"` since it's a web app.
Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to check is that the application is making the call on behalf of a Google Apps user.  If the user account is, for example, an @gmail account, the request will not be allowed.  The Google+ Domains API only works for Google Apps domain users, and only for requests within their domain.

Comment: Thanks Joanna.Also if I want my web app to be accessed by my colleagues,I need to specify the ip address of my machine in the redirect_uri.But when I try to modify the redirect_uri in the api console to http://10.66.126.156:8080/DomainWebApp/oauth2callback,it says "invalid uri".Is there any way to modify the redirect_uri?