# 403 Forbidden Request Using G+ API with good Access Token

Tags: google-api

Im trying to get a list of circles for a given user, im getting a good access_token back which iv tested here:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=

Output:

```
 "issued_to": "xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com",

 "audience": "xyz.apps.googleusercontent.com",

 "user_id": "xyz",

 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read",

 "expires_in": 2816,

 "access_type": "online"
```

Im sending the following headers to https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/circles

```
Array ( [0] => Authorization: Bearer accesscode

[1] => Content-length: 0 

[2] => Content-type: application/json )
```

Which is returning:

```
    Array ( [0] => { "error": { 
"errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "message": "Forbidden" } ], 
"code": 403, "message": "Forbidden" } } )
```

It seems like it thinks I havnt authorised the application access to my google account but I was prompted to allow access the first time I ran it and the access token verification output suggests that it has the correct permission scope.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this is greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Sam

Comment: See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474875/issue-while-fetching-google-circle-information-using-google-domain-api): [the Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) is only "for people who use Google Apps at college, at work, or at home." It appears that Google does not currently allow apps to list circles for regular Google+ accounts.