# Regarding google +domain api ............ getting an error 403 forbidden while listing the circle using installed application

Tags: java, json, api

i have just listing down the circle name in my google+domain api but getting an error of

i have used installed application-> other option  while making the application in google developer console

I am developing a small installed application wherein I am integrating with Google+ Domain API's. I am using OAuth2 authentication.I have generated client_id and client_secret for my Installed application from Google API console. Using Google+ Domain API's, I am able to generate the access token.

Also I am using ---some----@gmail.com       using gmail account

my code is as :-

```
enter code here


private static final String CLIENT_ID = "xyxxxxxxxx something in there";
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "Fhh1LYQ__UTso48snXHyqSQ2";


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

// List the scopes your app requires:
try{
List<String> SCOPE = Arrays.asList(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read");

final String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";


GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        new NetHttpTransport(),
        new JacksonFactory(),
        CLIENT_ID, // This comes from your Developers Console project
        CLIENT_SECRET, // This, as well
        SCOPE)
        .setApprovalPrompt("force")
        // Set the access type to offline so that the token can be refreshed.
        // By default, the library will automatically refresh tokens when it
        // can, but this can be turned off by setting
        // dfp.api.refreshOAuth2Token=false in your ads.properties file.
        .setAccessType("offline").build();

                       // This command-line se`enter code here`rver-side flow example requires the                user             to open the
    // authentication URL in their browser to complete the process. In most
    // cases, your app will use a browser-based server-side flow and your
    // user will not need to copy and paste the authorization code. In this
    // type of app, you would be able to skip the next 5 lines.
    // You can also look at the client-side and one-time-code flows for other
    // options at https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/
    String url = flow.newAuthorizationUrl().setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).build();
    System.out.println("Please open the following URL in your browser then " +
        "type the authorization code:");
    System.out.println("  " + url);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String code = br.readLine();
    // End of command line prompt for the authorization code.

    GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = flow.newTokenRequest(code)
        .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
        .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
        .setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
        .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        .addRefreshListener(new CredentialRefreshListener() {
          @Override
          public void onTokenResponse(Credential credential, TokenResponse tokenResponse) {
            // Handle success.
            System.out.println("Credential was refreshed successfully.");
          }

          @Override
          public void onTokenErrorResponse(Credential credential,
              TokenErrorResponse tokenErrorResponse) {
            // Handle error.
            System.err.println("Credential was not refreshed successfully. "
                + "Redirect to error page or login screen.");
          }
        })
        // You can also add a credential store listener to have credentials
        // stored automatically.
        //.addRefreshListener(new CredentialStoreRefreshListener(userId, credentialStore))
        .build();

    // Set authorized credentials.
    credential.setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
    // Though not necessary when first created, you can manually refresh the
    // token, which is needed after 60 minutes.
    credential.refreshToken();

    // Create a new authorized API client
    PlusDomains service = new PlusDomains.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName("Get-me").setRootUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/").build();


    PlusDomains.Circles.List listCircles = service.circles().list("me");
    listCircles.setMaxResults(5L);
    CircleFeed circleFeed = listCircles.execute();
    List<Circle> circles = circleFeed.getItems();

    // Loop until no additional pages of results are available.
    while (circles != null) {
      for (Circle circle : circles) {
        System.out.println(circle.getDisplayName());
      }

      // When the next page token is null, there are no additional pages of
      // results. If this is the case, break.
      if (circleFeed.getNextPageToken() != null) {
        // Prepare the next page of results
        listCircles.setPageToken(circleFeed.getNextPageToken());

        // Execute and process the next page request
        circleFeed = listCircles.execute();
        circles = circleFeed.getItems();
      } else {
        circles = null;
      }
    }
             }catch(Exception e)
          {
           System.out.println("Exception  "+e);
           }

           }
```

Its an INSTAlled Application -> other  Options........ in google developer console

i get the below error:---

Exception  com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}

Note: I have also enabled Google+ Domain API in my Google API Console.

REDIRECT_URI ="urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" since it's a Installed app. Any Suggestions?

Please help me out guys

Answer (score 2):

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21487075/3384047): [the Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) is only "for people who use Google Apps at college, at work, or at home."  It appears that Google does not currently allow apps to list circles for regular Google+ accounts.