# Google+ Domains 403 Forbidden when listing circles

Tags: node.js, express, google-plus

This is the source code that requests the permissions and try to list the circles,
What I want to make is to be able to list the circle's person, add/remove people from the circles but I get a forbidden error when I try to do it, and I get the access to those scopes.

```
    var express, router, nconf, OAuth2, oauth2Client, scopes, google;

    scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write'
    ];

    google = require('googleapis')
    nconf = require('nconf');
    OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
    express = require('express');
    router = express.Router();
    oauth2Client = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, SECRET_ID, REDIRECT_URL);

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
          access_type: 'offline', // 'online' (default) or 'offline' (gets refresh_token)
          scope: scopes // If you only need one scope you can pass it as string
        });
        res.redirect(url);
    });

    router.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
        console.log("code >> " + req.query.code);
        oauth2Client.getToken(req.query.code, function(err, tokens) {
          if(!err) {
            console.log("TOKENS >> " + JSON.stringify(tokens));
            oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
            var plusDomains = google.plusDomains('v1');
            plusDomains.circles.list({ userId: 'me', auth: oauth2Client }, function(err, circles) {
                  console.log('Result circles: ' + (err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(circles)));
                });
          }
          res.send({tokens: tokens});
        });
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You are sure the authenticated user is a Google Apps account and not a normal Google Account?

Comment: You have a very similar question to mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820085/google-api-for-plusdomains-circles-addpeople-in-rails-produces-403-forbidden

Comment: I think Abraham identified the issue: [the Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) is only "for people who use Google Apps at college, at work, or at home." It appears that Google does not currently allow apps to list circles for regular Google+ accounts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue while fetching Google+ Circle information using Google+ Domain API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474875/issue-while-fetching-google-circle-information-using-google-domain-api)