# Google API for plusDomains.circles.addPeople in Rails produces 403 Forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api

### Using: [Google API Ruby Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client)

```
class GooglePlus

  def self.follow_contact(contact, user = current_user)
    plus = GooglePlus.plus_domains
    GooglePlus.
        authorized(user).
        execute api_method: plus.circles.add_people,
                parameters: {circleId: "Following", userId: contact}
  end

  private

  def self.plus_domains
    GooglePlus.client.discovered_api('plusDomains')
  end

  def self.client
    require 'google/api_client'
    Google::APIClient.new(
        application_name: "My Application",
        application_version: "1.0.0",
        discovery_cache: ActiveSupport::Cache::Store
    )
  end

  def self.authorized(user = current_user)
    client = GooglePlus.client
    client.authorization.client_id = Rails.application.secrets.google[:client_id]
    client.authorization.client_secret = Rails.application.secrets.google[:client_secret]
    client.authorization.scope = %w^openid
                                    profile
                                    email
                                    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write
                                    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
                                    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
                                    https://www.google.com/m8/feeds^
    client.authorization.grant_type = 'refresh_token'
    client.authorization.refresh_token = user.socials.
        where(kind: Social.kinds[:google_plus]).
        select(&:verified?).first.token_secret
    client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
    client
  end

end
```

I know my OAuth key has the right permissions as I've set this line for my 'omniauth-google-oauth2' gem:

```
google = Rails.application.secrets.google

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, google[:client_id], google[:client_secret], {
    scope: %w^openid
              profile
              email
              https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write
              https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
              https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
              https://www.google.com/m8/feeds^.join(","),
    access_type: "offline",
    prompt: "consent"
  }
end
```

And that works fine.  Everything looks like it works up until the point where I execute the `client.execute api_method: plus.circles.add_people, parameters: {circleId: "Following", userId: contact}` I get back the following.

```
=> #<Google::APIClient::Result:0x000000093853e8
 @data=
  #<Google::APIClient::Schema::PlusDomains::V1::Circle:0x49c79f4 DATA:{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"forbidden", "message"=>"Forbidden"}], "code"=>403, "message"=>"Forbidden"}}>,
 @request=
  #<Google::APIClient::Request:0x0000000943f978
   @api_method=#<Google::APIClient::Method:0x3441238 ID:plusDomains.circles.addPeople>,
   @authenticated=nil,
   @authorization=
    #<Signet::OAuth2::Client:0x00000009450930
     @access_token="...",
     @additional_parameters={},
     @authorization_uri=
      #<Addressable::URI:0x4a2813c URI:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth>,
     @client_id=
      "...",
     @client_secret="...",
     @code=nil,
     @expires_in=3600,
     @expiry=60,
     @extension_parameters={},
     @grant_type="refresh_token",
     @id_token=
      "...",
     @issued_at=2014-09-13 00:49:08 -0400,
     @refresh_token="...",
     @scope=
      ["openid", "profile", "email",
       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.write",
       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
       "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
       "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"],
     @token_credential_uri=
      #<Addressable::URI:0x4a21e68 URI:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token>>,
   @body="",
   @headers=
    {"User-Agent"=>
      "My Application/1.0.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.7.1 Linux/3.13.0-32-generic\n (gzip)",
     "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip",
     "Content-Type"=>""},
   @parameters={"circleId"=>"Following", "usersId"=>"+contact_name"}>,
 @response=
  #<Faraday::Response:0x00000009386680
   @env=
    #<struct Faraday::Env
     method=:put,
     body=
      "{\n \"error\": {\n  \"errors\": [\n   {\n    \"domain\": \"global\",\n    \"reason\": \"forbidden\",\n    \"message\": \"Forbidden\"\n   }\n  ],\n  \"code\": 403,\n  \"message\": \"Forbidden\"\n }\n}\n",
     url=
      #<URI::HTTPS:0x00000009420370 URL:https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/circles/Following/people?usersId=%2Bcontact_name>,
     request=
      #<struct Faraday::RequestOptions
       params_encoder=Faraday::FlatParamsEncoder,
       proxy=nil,
       bind=nil,
       timeout=nil,
       open_timeout=nil,
       boundary=nil,
       oauth=nil>,
     request_headers=
      {"User-Agent"=>
        "My Application/1.0.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.7.1 Linux/3.13.0-32-generic\n (gzip)",
       "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip",
       "Content-Type"=>"",
       "Authorization"=>
        "Bearer ...",
       "Cache-Control"=>"no-store"},
     ssl=
      #<struct Faraday::SSLOptions
       verify=true,
       ca_file=
        "/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/google-api-client-0.7.1/lib/cacerts.pem",
       ca_path=nil,
       verify_mode=nil,
       cert_store=nil,
       client_cert=nil,
       client_key=nil,
       certificate=nil,
       private_key=nil,
       verify_depth=nil,
       version=nil>,
     parallel_manager=nil,
     params=nil,
     response=nil,
     response_headers=
      {"content-type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
       "date"=>"Sat, 13 Sep 2014 05:01:30 GMT",
       "expires"=>"Sat, 13 Sep 2014 05:01:30 GMT",
       "cache-control"=>"private, max-age=0",
       "x-content-type-options"=>"nosniff",
       "x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN",
       "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block",
       "server"=>"GSE",
       "alternate-protocol"=>"443:quic,p=0.002",
       "connection"=>"close",
       "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked"},
     status=403>,
   @on_complete_callbacks=[]>>
```

I've edited out keys and private information with a '**...**'. So it's not really telling me what it didn't like about my request.  Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have an expired token. From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2):

> 4. Refresh the access token, if necessary.
>
> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access
>   to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can
>   obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to
>   obtain new access tokens.

Have you tried setting the refresh token from the [omniauth auth hash](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#auth-hash)?

```
client.authorization.refresh_token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["refresh_token"]
```

HTH.

Comment: You can see that I call the `refresh_token` each time I perform the task in `def self.authorized` from `class GooglePlus`.  It's there in the code.

Comment: Yes, I see you are defining `refresh_token` each time, but it's getting the value from the database. Can you ensure this value is not expired?

Comment: Even when I get fresh credentials from Google I still come to this error message.  And I'm under the impression that this should consistently work by using the refresh token.