# 403 Forbidden response Google API

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, http-status-code-403, google-plus-domains

I am using the Google+ Api to create new circles for users. When I try and to a POST request I get a response like this:

```
 {
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden"
  }
}
```

This is the same response I get when I try to do the same request using Googles own Google API explorer https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/circles/insert which seems wierd to me. Why am I getting a forbidden response from googles own api expolrer? Could this be something wrong on their end?

I am using scribe OAuth library together with yincrash Google2Api
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

https://gist.github.com/yincrash/2465453

The request is created like this in an AsyncTask

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(Google2API.class)
                .apiKey(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
                .apiSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_KEY)
                .callback(GOOGLE_CALLBACK)
                .scope(SCOPE_WRITE)
                .scope(SCOPE_ME)
                .build();

        String postUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/plusDomains/v1/people/me/circles";


        String requestBody = "{\n" +
                "  \"displayName\": \"Circle Name\",\n" +
                "  \"description\": \"Circle with people you added\"" +
                "}";

        Token accessToken = new Token(sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_GOOGLE_KEY, ""), "");
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, postUrl);
        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        request.addPayload(requestBody);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();
```

It works fine to login and I have the access token saved.

Comment: Are you  performing this action as an user@gmail.com Google account or an user@example.com Google Apps for Business account?

Comment: I am trying to perfom this as a gmail user with a @gmail.com address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue while fetching Google+ Circle information using Google+ Domain API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474875/issue-while-fetching-google-circle-information-using-google-domain-api)

Comment: The Domains API does not work with user@gmail.com accounts.

Comment: @abraham Well is there an answer how to solve this with gmail accounts? Or is it not possible to create a circle on google plus for users who have a gmail account? It sounds really wierd to me.

Comment: You can't, the standard Google+ API is read only.