# Google Roads API - HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, api, google-api, request, google-roads-api

**Context and problem:**

I am trying to extract the speed limits of some roads using the [Google Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/overview). When I try to execute the [basic example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits) described on the website, I get the error `HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`. I am using the following code:

```py
# Import libraries
import urllib.request as req

# Extract road data
key = 'my_key'
mounted_url = 'https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?path=38.75807927603043,-9.03741754643809|38.6896537,-9.1770515|41.1399289,-8.6094075&key=' + key 
response = req.urlopen(mounted_url)
```

**What I have tried:**

I already checked the [API troubleshooting section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/errors) and several similar questions:

- [Getting a 403 - Forbidden for Google Service Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372453/getting-a-403-forbidden-for-google-service-account)
- [403 Forbidden Error from google API Javascript client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741001/403-forbidden-error-from-google-api-javascript-client)
- [403 Forbidden response Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880214/403-forbidden-response-google-api)
- [Google Drive API 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520538/google-drive-api-403-forbidden)

And I already tried the recommendations given on these sites:

- My API key is working fine. If I extract data using the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/quickstart), it works perfectly fine:

```py
# Extract directions data
mounted_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Disneyland&destination=Universal+Studios+Hollywood&key=' + key
response = req.urlopen(mounted_url)
```

- My [trial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI9az.png) is still active and the [API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0wff.png) is enabled.

**Extra details:**

This is the complete error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ffb4fce3ffb5> in <module>
      2 key = 'my_key'
      3 mounted_url = 'https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?path=38.75807927603043,-9.03741754643809|38.6896537,-9.1770515|41.1399289,-8.6094075&key=' + key
----> 4 response = req.urlopen(mounted_url)

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: any restrictions on the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exploring the documentation for a while, I found out that this is a license problem. It seems that the speed limits feature is the only non-available feature for the Roads API trial version:

[image: Licence]

**Sources:**

- [Google Roads API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits)

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with your code.

The code you provided matches exactly with what I have used to perform the same test.

There is an account issue with your permission to access that API. If you are unable to find the issue in your settings, I would recommend reaching out directly to Google.

Comment: Thank you @Emerson, you are right. This seems to be a license problem. I am working on it right now.